# Vertical-Center DIV next to a table

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, jsfiddle

I am having trouble centering a DIV next to a table within a DIV.
I have set the style of DIV and a table as inline-block and inline accordingly, but what happens is that the DIV is placed at the bottom of the table instead of center - level of the table (goal is to align it between "6" and "24"). Requirement is for it to work with the format being responsive.

Here is my code written within the JSFiddle.

```
<div class="Dboxes" style="color:white;">
<span class="Title"> Title </span><br>
<span class="Value" style="display:inline-block; background:orange;"> <img id="PPMain" class="MainImg" src="img/grnsqr.png" /> ## </span>

<table style="display: inline-block; background:green;">
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>
            <img id="PPVal2" class="ValImg" src="img/grnsqr.png">xx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>
            <img id="PPVal6" class="ValImg" src="img/grnsqr.png">yy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>
            <img id="PPVal24" class="ValImg" src="img/grnsqr.png">zz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>##</td>
        <td>
            <img id="PPVal##" class="ValImg" src="img/grnsqr.png">aa</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Help will be very appreciated, thank you very much

Also, link is right here https://jsfiddle.net/k3388j0w/1/

Comment: Im only seeing one div here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this answer your question?

http://codepen.io/mwvanmeurs/pen/GpwMZr

And btw, setting a `table` to `display: inline-block` is probably a bad idea.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
    <div class="container">
<table style="display: inline-block; background:green;">
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>
            <img id="PPVal2" class="ValImg" src="img/grnsqr.png">xx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>
            <img id="PPVal6" class="ValImg" src="img/grnsqr.png">yy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>
            <img id="PPVal24" class="ValImg" src="img/grnsqr.png">zz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>##</td>
        <td>
            <img id="PPVal##" class="ValImg" src="img/grnsqr.png">aa</td>
    </tr>
</table>
  <div class="other-div">
    <h1>Hey There!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I'm looking for. Could you please explain a little more about the display: flex; and align-items: center?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use divs to put your content into two columns, float them and then use padding to move your content down to the position you'd like it.

Like this https://jsfiddle.net/d5u712hv/

```
div.col {
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
}

div.col.first {
    width: 70px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
<div class="col first">
    <span class="Title"> Title </span><br>
    <span class="Value" style="display:inline-block; background:orange;"> <img id="PPMain" class="MainImg" src="img/grnsqr.png" /> ## </span>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <table style="display: inline-block; background:green;">
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>
            <img id="PPVal2" class="ValImg" src="img/grnsqr.png">xx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>
            <img id="PPVal6" class="ValImg" src="img/grnsqr.png">yy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>
            <img id="PPVal24" class="ValImg" src="img/grnsqr.png">zz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>##</td>
        <td>
            <img id="PPVal##" class="ValImg" src="img/grnsqr.png">aa</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change line 3 to the following: 
`<div class="Value" style="display:inline-block; background:orange; vertical-align:middle">`

and change line 5 to the following:
`<table style="display: inline-block; background:green; vertical-align:middle">`

and voila! :)

https://jsfiddle.net/k3388j0w/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can try just nesting the two objects inside an outer table, and remove borders like this (I also made the inner table have a class, and expressed that class in the CSS in place of the original "table" CSS):

```
.Outer
{
   border-collapse:collapse;
} 

.Outer td {
     border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3388j0w/3/)